# Sending a model for use throughout all views linked from a layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, view, model, controller

I am working on a web service built on ASP.NET MVC 4 and have run into some trouble figuring out how to manage a model after log in so that it is widely available to all action functions created in the back end.

For example) Let's say I have built a service that allows a user to log in and manage multiple databases. After he logs in he is redirected to a view that allows him to pick which database he would like to manage, which inherits the old layout. After he clicks on the database he wants to manage, the model of this database is passed to the index view of a manage controller which utilizes a different layout than before. All of the managing action links are coded in the layout but the model was passed to the index page. He needs the model to be available for all the ActionResults in the managing controller, but a model can't be passed to a layout, so this is where I'm stuck.

Does anyone know of any good references or guides on how I can utilize a model throughout a whole layout? Or something a long these lines? I'm not sure the technique I used for this problem was the best but I don't know how else to go about this. If anyone knows a better technique of going about this please let me know.

Thank you!